# Could not use \rule in chapter title in latest texlive

Tags: xetex, texlive, tex-core, debugging

Using XeLaTeX

In texlive 2014 (versions before May or texlive 2013 or older), one can use `\rule{width}{height}` in a chapter title. However, in latest texlive (versions after June) form ctan, use of `\rule` will cause instant stop and throw an error.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{a\rule{1cm}{0cm}b}

\end{document}
```

And here is the error

```
! Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.6 \chapter{a\rule{1cm}{0cm}b}
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Or could someone explain why it happens?

Perhaps this is not a bug but intended to do so. Or just because new texlive is in developing.

Comment: did it really work before? You can use `\chapter{a\protect\rule{1cm}{0cm}b}`

Comment: Doesn't with my TL 2013. But `\protet` does help, just as @DavidCarlisle recommended.

Comment: I tried with TL2010 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`\rule` has never been robust in LaTeX. You can use `\protect\rule` or you can use

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

which updates various things, including making `\rule` robust. Perhaps your previous document was using that package.

Comment: Thanks, this problem was found a few months ago after I updated my texlive and I used to treat it as a texlive problem. Minutes ago, I rolled back my texlive to 2013 and tried as you guys said, it was found that problem is package-depended.